# trouble in overriding a method in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
 Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing = true And components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Error: Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.

How can I call this without raising an error ?

Comment: are you overriding the method somewhere else as well? That might cause such an error. You might have the same method Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says you have two(or more) dispose methods with same signature. Try search for Dispose method in the same class, and if it is the same implementation, remove it.

Comment: The other one is generated automatically by the Form Designer.

Comment: @abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz: They why you are creating a Dispose for Form?

Comment: I used the online c# to vb.net converter , I got these new codes from there. Dispose method was not there in the original piece of code

Comment: I was just wondering if it was possible to call the dispose even though it is there in the Form Designer code

Comment: @abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz: Code converter stuff is strange. No you cannot call / create a method with same signature in the same class.